# Link to the sound section of the settings app from another app ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know similar questions have been asked before about how to open the settings app from another app. However this seems to only allow you to jump to the privacy settings of the sender app within the settings app. I need a way to jump directly to the sound settings menu of the settings app. Can this be done in objective-c specifically, I'm not interested in a swift solution. Thanks.

Comment: The only preference you can open is your own app's preference.  Any other urls that  you might use to open preferences are considered private API and will lead to rejection by Apple

Comment: ok, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Subsections inside Settings app is private. As I have made some research around it Apple rejects if you submit app for review. An Example case:

> Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a
>   private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App
>   Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs
>   change. Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future
>   submissions of this app may result in the termination of your Apple
>   Developer account, as well as removal of all associated apps from the
>   App Store.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app to provide the
>   associated functionality using public APIs or remove the functionality
>   using the "prefs:root" or "App-Prefs:root" URL scheme.
>
> If there are no alternatives for providing the functionality your app
>   requires, you can file an enhancement request.

So that means you are only allowed to use Main section like below.

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```